# Selecting 6 people from a group of 10 people with special conditions

Tags: combinatorics

Sorry for a misleading or such title, but i didn't know how to make it short enough. Anyways, if we have 10 people in a group such that 8 people eat apples, 1 eats pears and one eats watermelons, calculate the number of ways to select 6 people from the group of 10 . If the group has a pear eater, a watermelon eater must be selected as well and vice versa.
Edit:

For clarity the none of the 8 people who eats apples eats watermelons or pears, similarly the watermelon eater doesn't eat pears.
Special Thanks to Warren Hill

My attempt ::

$\binom{8}{6} + \binom{8}{4} = 98 $

Correct solution is 154. Why is this and why am I mistaken? 
Thanks.

Comment: For clarity the none of the 8 people who eats apples eats watermelons or pairs, similarly the watermelon eater doesn't eat pairs.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: I assume each person can only eat one fruit? IE there is no person who doesn't eat anything at all

Comment: I agree with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\binom{8}{6}$ part is correct. One of our options to choose a group as requested is just to pick from the apple eaters.

Another option would be to pick $4$ apple eaters and then $1$ pear eater and then $1$ watermelon eater. That would be:

$\binom{8}{4}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1}=\binom{8}{4}$

Overall you have $\binom{8}{6}+\binom{8}{4}$. Your solution is correct. The textbook is wrong.